# Standard way to record reporting information?

Tags: mongodb, logging, cassandra, hbase

I get logs for every call to my API. From these logs, I can retrieve interesting information that I use in a reporting dashboard.

My problem is that the number of those logs is getting bigger and bigger, and now I am looking for a new solution to store them.

Do I store logs or I store only the information I get from these logs?

Which database do I choose for storage (MySQL, HBase, MongoDB,Cassandra) ?